# Wordpress function wp_get_attatchment_url is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this customize function    functions.php to add image.

```
// Provider Image
function header($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_setting('header-image');

    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'header-image', array(
        'label' => 'Add Image',
        'section' => 'header-section',
        'settings' => 'header-image',
        'width' => 426,
        'height' => 642
    )));
}
add_action('customize_register','header');
```

After  then I echo

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attatchment_url(get_theme_mod('header-image')) ?>">
```

Field work in customization. But the page is just loading.

Comment: What information is obtained when you echo `get_theme_mod('header-image')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_get_attatchment_url` looks like mistype, it seems that correct name is [wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get the header Image URL by using this function

```
function get_header_image() {
$url = get_theme_mod( 'header_image', get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' ) );

if ( 'remove-header' == $url ) {
    return false;
}

if ( is_random_header_image() ) {
    $url = get_random_header_image();
}
```

Comment: This is not the  navigation header image, sir. I have a header section, I wanna customize that section image.